# Using phpunit CLI output in a php script

Tags: php, phpunit

The CLI output from a phpunit test contains useful information, such as:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.
F
Time: 7 seconds, Memory: 5.50Mb
There was 1 failure:
1) testHandler::testItem
Failed asserting that page text contains <itest New Family Name>.

Driver.php:632
testHandler.php:29
S163.php:18
testHandler.php:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 97, Failures: 1.
```

I'd like to send this information to my test tracking software by way of a POST through php curl.

However I can't find a way of catching the information in my test class (which extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase).

Any help / thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way if you have a custom build solution seems to be:

```
phpunit | curl -X http://url
```

or

```
phpunit 2>&1 > output.txt && cat output.txt | curl -X http://url
```

or something like that.

If you are using a proper Continuous Integration server look into the `--log-junit` and `--coverage-clover` or other output formats like `--log-json`.

I don't see any reason why you would want to get the output programmatically while the test are running. It just seems to be a lot more work than gain. There are ways to extend PHPUnit to integrate it with bugtrackers though. Have a look at the [**`PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener).